# How to build a Random Walk with non-negative values?

Tags: r

I would like to build a random walk with a certain number of innovations (e.g. 10000) and non-negative values.

I tried:

```
Value <- c(100) #initial Value 
n <- 10000      #number of innovations 

for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  Value[i+1] <- Value[i] + rnorm(1)
  
  if(Value[i+1] < 0){
  repeat{
    Value[i+1] <- Value[i] + rnorm(1)
  }
  if(Value[i+1] >0){
    break
  }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work if the value becomes negative. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are several options. One is replacing the `repeat` loop for a `while` loop. Like this:

```
Value <- c(100) #initial Value 
n <- 10000      #number of innovations 
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  Value[i+1] <- Value[i] + rnorm(1)
  
  while(Value[i+1] < 0){
      Value[i+1] <- Value[i] + rnorm(1)
    }
}
```

You can check that none value of `Value` is negative by:

```
any(Value < 0)
```

Comment: The less verbose solution doesn't do the same thing as the original loop intention.

Comment: Hi @Dason, would you expand on you comment ? I checked and the only difference is that the more verbose answer is doing  `rnorm`until it reaches a non-negative value while the less verbose convert to positive any result of `rnorm` Both achieves a random series of non-negative numbers.

Comment: The original can increase then decrease. The less verbose version will always increase and it would be impossible to decrease.

Comment: Thanks @Dason for the correction. I have deleted the less verbose solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can either try this

```
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
    Value[i+1] <- Value[i] + abs(rnorm(1))}
```

Or

```
for(i in 1:(n-1)){
  a = rnorm(1)
  while(a<0){a = rnorm(1)}
  Value[i+1] <- Value[i] + a}
```